# How Can I set $.ajax data the List<Entity> from Controller's ModelMap?

Tags: ajax, list, spring-mvc

I want to realize a simple function of shopping cart, users can see the goods they added into the shopping cart, when a user click the buy button, he can buy all the goods in the shopping cart.

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shoppingcart",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String shoppingCart(ModelMap model) {
    //get goods info of the user's shopping cart
    List<ShoppingCartInfo> shoppingCartInfos = shoppingService.findShoppingCardInfoByUserId(getCurrentUserId());
    model.put("shoppingCartInfos",shoppingCartInfos);
    return "shoppingcart.jsp";
}
```

JSP

```
<body>
<%@include file="common/navbar.jsp"%>
<div class="container">
    <table id="shoppingCartTable" class="table table-striped table-hover results ellipsis-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>编号</th>
            <th>商品标题</th>
            <th>价格</th>
            <th>购买数量</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            //show goods info
            <c:forEach var="shoppingCartInfo" items="${shoppingCartInfos}" varStatus="count">
                <tr>
                    <td >${count.index + 1}</td>
                    <td><a href="${AppContext}item/showItem/${shoppingCartInfo.itemId}">${shoppingCartInfo.itemTitle}</a></td>
                    <td>${shoppingCartInfo.cost}</td>
                    <td>${shoppingCartInfo.itemNum}</td>
                </tr>
                addData(${shoppingCartInfo})
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="col-md-offset-10" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" id="buyAllItemsBtn">购买</a>
        <a href="javascript:history.back(-1);" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">退出</a>
    </div>

</div>


<%@include file="common/footer.jsp"%>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#shoppingCartTable').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "${AppContext}resources/lang/datatables_zhcn.json"
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
})

$('#buyAllItemsBtn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"${AppContext}buyer/buyAllItems",
        /*traditional: true,*/
        data:${shoppingCartInfos},//  **the error is here**
        success:function (result) {
            if(result.resultStatus == "SUCCESS") {

            }else {
                showModal("购买失败",result.resultMsg,"");
            }
        }
    })
})
```

ERROR:
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2QEQ.png)

My questions:

(1) data:${shoppingCartInfos} I want to send the data to ${AppContext}buyer/buyAllItems, but it didn't success
(2) the ${shoppingCartInfos} value is [ShoppingCartInfo{shoppingcartId=4, userId=22, itemId=10}], the object have the List object class name, can I delete it?

I'm not familiar with the knowledge, thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JSON stringify. It might be what you need: http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/javascript-object-to-string-tutorial/

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
        infos: ${shoppingCartInfos}
});

$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"${AppContext}buyer/buyAllItems",
        data:data,
```

Comment: Still have an error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
 data:JSON.stringify({
                shoppingCartInfos:[ShoppingCartInfo{shoppingcartId=4, userId=22, itemId=10]
}),

it's not the standard format like [{},{},{}], beacuse the list have the "ShoppingCartInfo" class name, I think the error is caused by this

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I override the ShoppingCartInfo Class's toString() methods

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ShoppingCartInfo{" +
            "shoppingcartId=" + shoppingcartId +
            ", userId=" + userId +
            ", itemId=" + itemId +
            ", itemTitle='" + itemTitle + '\'' +
            ", cost=" + cost +
            ", itemNum=" + itemNum +
            ", createTime=" + createTime +
            '}';
}
```

delete the ShoppingCartInfo is ok